# Debug Spring MVC with eclipse and Tomcat issue

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have deployed a Spring MVC application on Tomcat server(eclipse IDE). The application comes up fine but some data is added to list.So wanted to debug .
I have added debug points and did "Debug on server" ,the server started in debug mode but it says : Source not found.in the debug view.The control doesnot come to code in application code.

Very new to java programming , so I am sure not what i have asked is a silly question .Please help me.Let me know if i need more details.

Note I donot use maven or  anything like that.

Thanks
Siddhi

Answer (score 6):

Follow the steps given below:

1. Start the Tomcat server instance from within Eclipse;
2. After the server instance has started, open the Debug view.  Make sure that the running threads of the application are visible in the view in a hierarchical tree-like structure.  The application name should be at the top in this hierarchy;
3. Stop the Tomcat server instance.  The name of the application should still be visible in the Debug view;
4. Right click the application name and choose Edit Source Lookup;
5. Select the application root directory as one of the locations where Eclipse should look for the source code;
6. Start Tomcat server instance again.

After the instance has come up, you should be able to debug your source code just fine.

Comment: Thanks @manish! FYI this worked great for me using the Jetty embedded container too, as part of Spring Boot.