# Server required in eclipse for spring boot

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and I would want to know the basics of it. I am creating a project with jHipster. When I install gulp on my system  I can see the project running at port 9000. I however want to deploy the same application on my local using tomcat apache server.

Can I debug my code in java using the same server installed during the time of spring boot or do I need a separate server like apache?

Comment: Do you mean you want to launch spring boot web application in debug mode?Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113939/how-to-debug-spring-boot-application-with-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

From [**JHipster documentation "Profiles"**](https://jhipster.github.io/profiles/) :

If you're using **Maven Wrapper** (`mvnw`)

```
./mvnw package
```

If you're using **Gradle Wrapper** (`mvnw`)

```
./gradlew bootRepackage
```

Should produce WAR with development profile as

> By default, JHipster will use the `dev` profile

I think you can deploy this WAR on your usual Tomcat