# How to Debug spring-boot maven project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have spring-boot mvc project - maven.

Specifically I want to debug `@Controller` class.

I converted it to eclipse project with

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

Then in eclipse, I tried to Debug it on Server (Tomcat 7), but got an error

> The server does not support version 3.1 of the J2EE Web module
>   specification.

In Facets configurations, it doesn't allow me to choose any other version of 'Dynamic Web Module' from 3.1.

I also tried to debug like that: from project root I ran:

```
mvndebug spring-boot::run
```

And then connected debug-remote, but when I opened the page in browser, break point of the controller didn't trigger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug Spring Boot application with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113939/how-to-debug-spring-boot-application-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `eclipse:eclipse` cause it's deprecated very long time...If you like to debug the Spring Boot application you can do this [via](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html):

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000"
```

You need to start Eclipse via Debug configuration.

The execution `mvnDebug...` will debug Maven itself which is not what you want to do.